Likelihood for a single path from a Lévy process
I'm trying to calculate the large $N$ limit for the likelihood of single realized path from a Lévy process sampled at N equally spaced times between ]0, T]
$$
L(y_1, y_2, \dots, y_N) = \prod_{k=1}^N f(y_k - y_{k-1}, T/N)
$$
with $y_0 = 0$ and $y_N = y_T$.
I suspect that the result should be proportional to the single step likelihood, i.e.
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}L(y_1, y_2, \dots, y_N)\propto f(y_N - y_0, T)
$$
but I'm not able to demonstrate that.
In the limit, each possible increment should be observed according to the law $f$ on any path, so the only difference in the paths would be a permutation of the increments?
Sorry if this is a trivial question, very glad if someone can point me to a reference if so.
Thanks
